# Can multiple instances of temporal be backed by the same database?

Tags: database, multiple-instances, temporal-workflow

This is a "Yes/No" question: Can multiple instances of temporal be backed by the same database?

I want to use a single (HA, geo-redundant) Cloud SQL to store workflow state with multiple (geo-redundant) workers sharing that DB.

I can't find anything in the documentation that answers this question.

Comment: Your question can have multiple interpetations. What do you mean by "multiple instances  of Temporal"? Multiple clusters or multiple hosts? What do you mean by "the same database"? The same DB host of the same logical DB running on the same host?
Would you describe what are you looking for? Have you looked into Temporal mulit-cluster setups?

Comment: @maxim multiple hosts (which may or may not be running in multiple clusters). “The same database” means what it means - I don’t understand how that could have multiple meanings, but I’ll try to make it clearer: “the same, single database server instance, which is not running on the same machine”. I want HA and complete redundancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporal out of the box provides support for multi-node setup. The only requirement is that nodes should be able to talk to each other and the backend database to maintain the cluster membership.

The temporal cluster consists of nodes that play different roles: front-end, history, worker, matching. The roles can be collocated, but it is not recommended for production deployments. Any of the nodes can be added and removed at any time without downtime assuming that enough capacity of each type is maintained to support the application load.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Do the nodes learn about each other via the shared database?

Comment: Hosts use gossip to maintain the membership and use the database to maintain the list of seed nodes for the gossip.